# Using variables inside for loops

Tags: bash

I'm trying to compare sizes of files inside two directories. 
My problem is that when I store the sizes of the files inside of a "for" loop, my variable takes all the sizes at once instead of taking them one by one.

Here is the part of my code that is problematic :

```
for dir1Files in dir1/*
do
    sizeFile1=`stat -c%s $dir1Files`
    for dir2Files in dir2/*
    do
        sizeFile2=`stat -c%s $dir2Files`
        diffSize=$((sizeFile1-sizeFile2))
        echo "$diffSize"
    done
done
```

I realised, thanks to `set -x`, that my variables `sizeFile1` and `sizeFile2` are not integers. Instead, they are a few lines long and contain the sizes of my files in directories, with "one line = one integer", if that makes sense. 
For example, with three files in dir1, my variable `sizeFile1` is :

```
12500
14534
23000
```

What I would like is for my variable to vary from 12500 to 14534 to 23000. How should I do that ? I'm guessing I need to change my "for" into something else ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused, isn't bash non-typed ? And isn't the problem there that the "for" loop gives the 3 values of sizeFile1 at the same time instead of one by one ?

Comment: @Sratard, no, the loop assigns the values one at a time, and all arithmetic in bash coerces values to integers; built-in math fails for numbers that can't be parsed as ints.

Comment: (BTW, it'd be much better to name the variables `dir1File` and `dir2File`, singular, since they only contain one filename at a time)

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior on bash 5.0.11, which version do you have?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, so the problem is how I used the "stat" function ?

Comment: Are you saying that the output of `stat -c%s $dir1Files` for a single file contains multiple lines?

Comment: The code as-given doesn't reproduce any problem at all, at least, not with any version of `stat` I'm familiar with. Please show your `set -x` output.

Comment: Well, it could produce problems if you had filenames with glob characters or whitespace. To fix that, fix your quoting; `stat -c%s "$dir1Files"`, not just bare `stat -c%s $dir1Files`

Comment: I'm using version 4.4.20 @oguzismail

Comment: See Charles' comment above. Do you have files whose name contain glob-active characters like `*`, `?`, etc?

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy you were right, the problem was because of whitespace, using `stat -c%s "$dir1Files"` fixed it !

Comment: BTW, consider making a habit of running your scripts through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here; among other things, it'll detect unquoted expansions.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in this is broken 100% of the time, but it certainly *can be* broken if run with unusual filenames present. To make this code more robust:

- Use quotes whenever you expand a variable. This prevents a file named `dir1/ *` (with the space in its name) from being replaced with a list of all files in the current directory when generating a `stat` command line.
- Use `shopt -s nullglob` to make the loops not run at all when no glob matches exist, instead of running with the glob expression as a filename itself.

```
shopt -s nullglob  # prevent dir1/* from ever evaluating to itself
for dir1File in dir1/*; do
    sizeFile1=$(stat -c%s "$dir1File")
    for dir2File in dir2/*; do
        sizeFile2=$(stat -c%s "$dir2File")
        diffSize=$((sizeFile1-sizeFile2))
        echo "$diffSize"
    done
done
```